# What is the best sharing model for Category sharing of data

Tags: security, sharing

For My Application, I have to build a Category wise sharing, which means all data, objects related to Category A should be shared to a group of users and Category B should be not.

So i have different objects all of which have a lookup to category object.

So, wanted to understand what should be the best way to share the data.

I can think of Apex sharing but i want to know if there is a better way to share the data without involving apex

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Please [edit], don't comment).

Comment: I can think of Apex sharing but i want to know if there is a better way to share the data without involving apex